# is there a pragmatic reason to use "if (0 == p) " instead of "if (!p)"?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I'm inclined to write if statements by using logical negation operator:

```
if (!p)
    some_code();
```

Some people around me tend to use explicit comparison, so that the code looks like:

```
if (FOO == p)
    some_code();
```

where FOO is one of **false**, **FALSE**, **0**, **0.0**, **NULL**, etc.

I prefer the short form because it is:

- `operator!=` friendly
- `generic programming` friendly
- laconic (and even *more beautiful*, as for me)

What are the **pragmatic** benefits of writing this otherwise (if any)?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an answer that isn't subjective.

Comment: People who compare directly with true and false should be fired/otherwise avoided, imo.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt: Especially if they're comparing a _pointer_ with `true` or `false`!

Comment: it's strange that there are no comments mentioning generic functions, where `!p` introduces a kind of requirement to type of p

Comment: @Mike Mueller: I'd like to give it a try, if there will be an answer that helps me with code-review debates (that are rare, but happen sometimes) I'll accept that. You know, like "subjective, but works for me and all those guys whose commits I will reject" :-)

Comment: I've just realized what looks to me as an interesting misconception: those who think that explicit expression makes code more `readable` tend to think that by specifying an explicit value they give the reader _a hint_ of what is the actual type of `p`, as if one glance at literal gave you enough information to guess its type. I'd emphasize these two contra-arguments: (1) guessing type from literal is not more than guessing (which is as almost as bad as _assuming_) and (2) it's better to write the code so that reader is not required to guess the type of `p`

Comment: @Heath -- I've often wondered why people who compare to true stop at just one.  After all, if `if (x == true)` is better than `if (x)`, wouldn't `if ((x == true) == true)` be better still?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some claim that the pragmatic benefit is that programmers will find it easier to understand if you explicitly compare against NULL, FALSE, 0, etc., whereas the logical operator may be confusing to people who don't understand how implicit conversions and booleans work in C/C++.

(Disclaimer: I don't share this view myself. `if (p) ...` and `if (!p)...` are the idiomatic ways to express this in C and C++, and programmers who have trouble understanding them have no business touching C or C++ code.  Heath Hunnicutt's comment is dead on.)

Comment: although there are plenty of good comments - this answer is the best regarding original question. It tells about the benefits that are seen by "some programmers", implying that there is an army of others (including me) that see no such benefit

Answer (score 23):

To contrast [@Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187692/is-there-a-pragmatic-reason-to-use-if-0-p-instead-of-if-p/5187729#5187729) I would say use `!` for readability. If you find you are overlooking it then get your eyes tested. What's next? Avoid 1, use 3 - 2 instead?

Comment: LOL! Reminds me of a machine where we used `PI/PI` to represent "one" for storage efficiency, as it took less than the digit string `1`.

Comment: @Troubadour: we think similarly here - for me the rule `readable` contains subrule "not giving details I don't need at the moment"

Comment: Clearly if your readers are overlooking the `!` in `!p`, the only sensible thing to do is to write `!!!p`. Multiple exclamations marks work on the internet, they'll work in code too.

Comment: I'll argue that it is very easy to over look in compound conditions but that may be an internal parser defect :)

Comment: @Troubadour: I would argue (as @glowcoder) that while for booleans and pointers I could find it natural, for integers it hinges on the fact that integers are implicitly convertible to booleans, and thus I'd rather see `p != 0` there.

Comment: I totally agree with Troubadour (which I expressed as +1). But despite this answer's popularity, I can't accept it as the question was about the benefits of doing it the other way (even if the benefit is _mythical_).

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I agree that `!` is only suitable for pointers and bools and I was an early upvoter of @glowcoder's answer. I must admit my answer was written more in a "is it me?" moment regarding the readability issue of `!` and so I mistakenly neglected to address that important point.

Answer (score 13):

Use `(0 == p)` or `(p == 0)` for readability. That `!` is easier to overlook at first glance than `== 0`

Use `(0 == p)` if you have a habit of ignoring compiler warnings, and want to know when you use = rather than ==.

Comment: the `readability` concept here has a flaw - reader might make wrong assumptions on type of `p`, e.g. reader might thing it's pointer while it is an integer or double, so the next step for this kind of readability would be the `hungarian notation`

Comment: You should use a constant that clearly indicates type, I just didn't copy-paste the above using 0.0 or nullptr or NULL

Comment: I actually find `if (p)` and `if (!p)` a lot more readable than `if (p == 0)`, `if (p == 1)` or `if (p != 0)`.

Comment: @Dan I only find it more readable if p is of type bool. Otherwise I prefer the check that will convert it to bool. It almost as bad as the people who use !!p to test class objects for truth.

Comment: `if (! p)` should be enough to make people realize the ''not''.

Comment: +1, I find that people tend to read "p does (or does not) equal true" more correctly then "not p". Even in English we tend to say "if switch is off then..." rather than "if it is not the case that the switch is on then..."

Comment: @Erik: if you have a habit of ignoring warning, turn on `-Werror`

Comment: @Martin sure, for non-boolean and non-pointer types I actually use `if (p == NUMBER)` because I feel it brings across my intent better. I do always always use `if (p)` or `if (! p)` (like user unknown, I do actually put a space between the ! and the variable) for booleans and when testing if pointers are null (read is "if pointer is valid/invalid" rather than "if pointer is equal to zero/null").

Comment: I know I'm a heretic (and my code might seem ugly), but years ago I hardwired myself to never leave whitespace before any assignment operation (a= b= 0; b+= 1) and always use whitespace before comparison operators (a == b). Since then, I never fell in the trap of typing "=" instead of "==".

Answer (score 11):

It depends on what p represents.

If p represents a boolean/logical value, then `(!p)` seems most appropriate - comparing to "FALSE" is generally discouraged. I don't anticipate this being of much debate.

If p represents a value, like a counter, then `(p == 0)` or `(0 == p)` seems appropriate. (There is usually a hot debate between the two. I find the first more readable, but the second avoids some very serious bugs.) Aside from which of the two options is better, I don't anticipate this being a debate (as in, it should compare to 0.)

If p represents a pointer, then you have some issues. A competent C++ programmer should know that `(!p)` will tell you if it's null or not. However, the idea of the readability of this is a grey area, and I see this being a highly contested debate.

Comment: regarding serious bugs --> serious compilers warn about unintended assignment in conditions. +1 for treating booleans integers, and pointers differently. For pointers, C++0x would suggest `p != nullptr`

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm a bit bored of the implicit conversion from int to boolean. I don't think it adds much to the C language any more. In C89 where there's no boolean type it's perfectly reasonable to use an integer as a boolean, in which case the conversion leads to good-looking code. I see why it can't be removed, especially when dealing with libraries that for compatibility reasons can't be changed to return boolean now there is one. But I certainly don't think it should be used in all cases.

Sometimes, a 0 integer value means "there isn't one", but sometimes it means "there is one and it's zero". So I'm happy with:

```
users = get_number_of_users();
if (users) {
    // there are users
    ...
} else {
    // there aren't users
}
```

I'm not at all keen on:

```
length = strlen(ptr);
if (length) {
    // there is length? OK, sort of...
} else {
    // there isn't length? No, wait, there *is* a length, that length is 0
}
```

So there's your pragmatic reason to write `if (length == 0)` in preference to `if (!length)`. "If not length" makes no sense in *English*, so isn't necessarily what you should be writing in code either.

Admittedly, `0` was invented as a special place-holder to mean "there aren't any". But the realization that in many contexts it could be treated as a number like any other was an important breakthrough in the history of mathematics, and I don't think we should discard that just because C provides us with a syntax to treat it specially again ;-) If you want to know whether a number is 5, you compare it with 5, and normally I think the same should hold for 0.

Comment: idiomatic `if (!p || !*p)` doesn't make sense in English either, but it doesn't mean anyone should  stop using it. If a programmer wants to code in English he would better use pascal rather than C/C++.

Comment: @Andrey: nevertheless, given two options with little to choose between them, we must choose based on small reasons. Perhaps you slightly prefer `if (!length)`. I slightly prefer `if (length==0)`. I *think* the reason I prefer it is that I find it to express the intention more directly. Also, I try moderately hard not to use `if (!p || !*p)`. If I'm doing the same thing for null pointers as empty strings, then why has my data scheme allowed that redundancy to slip through? Sometimes it's unavoidable, sometimes you can fix it.

Comment: You added `if (length)` into consideration - and this form is **bad** enough. Note that original question only touched idiomatic `if (!length)` form, which I am quite comfortable with in all contexts. I prefer it rather than ambiguous `0==x` / `x==0`.

Answer (score 2):

One as-yet-unmentioned benefit to the `if (!Foo)` version is that it will work with classes that used the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).  In classes that implement that, comparison operators of classes will fail (e.g. `Foo==0` will be undefined) but `!Foo` will call a conversion operator on Foo, returning a pointer to member function (or null pointer, if `Foo` should be treated as false).  A number of Boost classes, like shared_ptr, use this technique.

Answer (score 1):

In a really complex conditional, using an explicit == can help make it more readable. Unfortunately, it also opens the door for writing x = 0 instead of x == 0, but you can avoid this by writing 0 == x instead(so that 0 = x will throw an error).

It could also be habit from other languages where you'd have to cast to a boolean otherwise.

Comment: interestingly, explicit comparison will also bring additional parentheses making complex conditional even more complex

Answer (score 1):

I would place a space before and after !:  `( ! p)` so ! stands out.  But I would restrict this usage to only integer types including pointers.  I would use `==` for floating points because it will cause you and others to pause and think if `0.0 == p` is really appropriate versus specifying a tolerance.

If p is an instance of a class, `( ! p)` should be used by defining operator! to avoid an implicit conversion with `0.0 == p`.

Comment: ok, and what if you, as the original code author, know that `p` provides `operator!=`?

Answer (score 1):

If the language is C and if p is a pointer then if (p) and if (!p) should be avoided.

C (the language) doesn't specify that the null pointer will be boolean false.
It does say that 0 casted to a pointer (either implicitly or explicitly) will give the null pointer.

Therefore testing p rather than p == NULL are not necessarily the same, and on some older hardware they are definitely not the same since the null pointer is actually a pointer to a particular memory page.

You can however guarantee that 0 and therefore NULL are equal to the null pointer, because C says they must be.

Comment: PS: I don't know how this applies to C++

Comment: C99, 6.5.5.3p5 The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).   

C99, 6.5.9p5 If one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant, the null pointer constant is converted to the type of the pointer.


C99, 6.3.2.3p3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.

Answer (score 0):

the only pragmatic reason i see there is that in the second case the type of values considered for comparison is more explicit (es. foo == null foo is a ponter type, !foo can't say if it is a pointer, a bool, etc)

Comment: yeah, and the great part is that you don't have to care what p is :)

Answer (score 0):

With **`if (0 == p)`** you force the comparison to enter that "if scope" in that case. I mean, it will be clear that you want to do that in case **`p is equals 0`**. By just using **`(!p)`** its not explicit what you want to know. It could be **`null, false`**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`if (Foo)` and `if (!Foo)` seem to imply `Foo` is a boolean variable, at least for me.  That being said, as long as your identifier is sufficiently descriptive it really shouldn't matter.  I would use `!Foo` for new code, but follow existing conventions if there are any.  Consistency trumps all.